# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpython-dev on Ubuntu. Compiling C program using PyObject

Tags: python, c, ubuntu, gcc

I have the following C program which I need to integrate with Python:

```
#include <Python.h>

PyObject* get_details(){
    PyObject *details = PyDict_New();
    PyObject *key, *value;
    key = PyUnicode_FromString("full name");
    value = PyUnicode_FromString("Pete Graham");
    PyDict_SetItem(details, key, value);
    return details;
}
```

I can compile the program on OS X using:

```
gcc -I /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/Headers \
-L /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib \
-lpython3.4 get_person_dict.c
```

I get an error when I try and compile the program on Ubuntu `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpython3.4.`

This is the command I'm using on Ubuntu I've tried various values for the python lib path.

```
gcc -I /usr/include/python3.4 \
-L /usr/local/lib \
-lpython3.4 get_person_dict.c
```

I installed python with `sudo apt-get install python3.4-dev` the version of Ubuntu trusty64 and is being used on Vagrant.

Comment: Try `locate Python.h` and see if that finds anything.

Comment: Also a quick search on http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=Python.h&mode=exactfilename&suite=wily&arch=any seems to indicate that you might need `libpython3.4-dev`.

Comment: The location of `Python.h` is `/usr/include/python3.4/Python.h` so should be found by `-I /usr/include/python3.4`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several things wrong.

As @JJHakala has advised you,

```
python3.4-config --libs
```

will tell you the libraries you need in order to link an executable with the Python 3.4
runtime, viz:

```
-lpython3.4m -lpthread -ldl  -lutil -lm
```

And

```
python3.4-config --ldflags
```

will tell you *all* the options you must pass to the linker to achieve the
same end, viz:

```
-L/usr/lib/python3.4/config-3.4m-x86_64-linux-gnu \
-L/usr/lib -lpython3.4m -lpthread -ldl  -lutil -lm \
 -Xlinker -export-dynamic -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions
```

So let's try putting those linker options into your gcc commandline instead of 
the linker options you've used. Your commandline was:

```
$ gcc -I /usr/include/python3.4 -L/usr/local/lib -lpython3.4 get_person_dict.c
```

with linker options:

```
-L/usr/local/lib -lpython3.4
```

So we'll try:

```
$ gcc -I /usr/include/python3.4 `python3.4-config --ldflags` get_person_dict.c
```

That doesn't work. The output is:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
/build/buildd/glibc-2.21/csu/../sysdeps/x86_64/start.S:114: undefined reference to `main'
/tmp/ccrczTMI.o: In function `get_details':
get_person_dict.c:(.text+0x9): undefined reference to `PyDict_New'
get_person_dict.c:(.text+0x17): undefined reference to `PyUnicode_FromString'
get_person_dict.c:(.text+0x25): undefined reference to `PyUnicode_FromString'
get_person_dict.c:(.text+0x40): undefined reference to `PyDict_SetItem'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

We have undefined references to all the Python 3.4 functions that are called in
`get_person_dict.c`, and an undefined reference to `main`

The reason for that the undefined Python 3.4 references is that you were, 
and still are, passing the libraries to the linker *before* any file that calls functions defined in them. So
the linker comes to each library on the commandline in turn and says to itself:
*Have I yet noted any calls to undefined functions that have definitions in this library?
No. Then I don't need to link anything from this library*. And passes on.
After all the libraries have been ignored, it reaches your `get_person_dict.c` (or in
reality, the temporary object file `/tmp/ccrczTMI.o` that the compiler has
previously compiled from `get_person_dict.c`). There is finds undefined
references `PyDict_New`, `PyUnicode_FromString` `PyUnicode_FromString`,
`PyDict_SetItem`. But now there are no libraries left in which they might be defined.
The libraries in which they *are* defined are water under the bridge, so
the undefined references remain as linkage errors.

In the linkage sequence, files that *need* definitions must appear *before*
the files that *provide* the definitions.

Well that's easily corrected:

```
$ gcc -I /usr/include/python3.4  get_person_dict.c `python3.4-config --ldflags`
```

Now the output is:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
/build/buildd/glibc-2.21/csu/../sysdeps/x86_64/start.S:114: undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The linker has now found definitions for all the Python 3.4 functions. But it
still says it can't find a definition for `main`.

The reason for that is the the C "program" you've posted isn't a program, it's
just a definition of a function `PyObject* get_details()`. Every C program,
by definition, has a `main` function, which is the first function called. For
that reason, when you try to link some files and libraries into a C program,
as you are trying to do, the linker automatically links startup code that calls
`main`. But you have no `main`.

So you can't link your `get_person_dict.c` as a program, even if you get the
linkage order right. You can *compile* it, without linking it:

```
$ gcc -I /usr/include/python3.4  -c -o get_person_dict.o get_person_dict.c
```

That gives you an object file `get_person_dict.o` which contains the compiled, but
unlinked, definition of `PyObject* get_details()`. It will be identical to the
temporary object file `/tmp/ccrczTMI.o` that gcc compiled for you without being
told to in the failed compile-and-link attempt above.

But having compiled your `get_person_dict.o` like that, you can link *it* in
a program, as long as you also link - *after it* - the other libraries that
define the functions that it calls:

**get_person_prog.c**

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <stdio.h>

extern PyObject * get_details(); // Ought to be put in a header

int main(void)
{
    PyObject * pyobj = get_details();
    if (pyobj) {
        puts("Got the details");
    }
    return  0;
}
```

Compile that:

```
$ gcc -I /usr/include/python3.4  -c -o get_person_prog.o get_person_prog.c
```

Link your object files and libraries, in the right order, to make a program `prog`:

```
$ gcc -o prog get_person_prog.o get_person_dict.o `python3.4-config --ldflags`
```

Run:

```
$ ./prog
Got the details
```

Comment: Thanks for this very informative answer. I'd foolishly removed the main function from my C code example so it was shorter. I'm primarily a Python programmer so the gcc options were baffling me!

Answer (score 1):

In debian / jessie

```
python3.4-config --ldflags
```

tells what link parameters should be used, which should work on Ubuntu also. The command is in `python3.4-dev` package.

```
python3.4-config --libs
```

Tells the names of the libraries needed when linking.

The output

```
-L/usr/lib/python3.4/config-3.4m-x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib -lpython3.4m 
-lpthread -ldl -lutil -lm -Xlinker -export-dynamic 
-Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions`
```

contains `-lpython3.4m` i.e not `-lpython3.4` as in the question. Using it instead should help with this specific problem.

Comment: How would the output of this command be used in the gcc command? The output for me is `-L/usr/lib/python3.4/config-3.4m-x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib -lpython3.4m -lpthread -ldl  -lutil -lm  -Xlinker -export-dynamic -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions`